# How do I make part of my route optional?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have this route, which overrides a resource-generated route:

```
match "make_tiles(/:tile_type,(:finish))" => "tiles#new", :as => :make_tiles
```

This allows for nice URLs like `/make_tiles/two_two,matte`

But I'd like the option to use: `/make_tiles/two_two` also. Currently only `/make_tiles/two_two,` works.

How can I get rid of the trailing comma requirement?

Comment: Have you tried moving the paren like so: `make_tiles(/:tile_type(,:finish))`?

Comment: Yes, it didn't work. It just sent `{"tile_type"=>"four_four,matte"}` as a single parameter with both values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a comma to separate fields, and I'm not sure why you'd want to. A comma is not a very good field separator for routes. If you really insist on doing it this way, have the options go into one parameter and separate them manually:

```
match "make_tiles(/:tile_type_and_finish)" => "tiles#new", :as => :make_tiles
```

Then in your controller

```
(tile_type,finish) = params[:tile_type_and_finish].split(",") if params[:tile_type_and_finish].present?
```

The reason your way isn't allowed is that rails defines the parameter separator as a constant in ActionDispatch::Routing:

```
SEPARATORS = %w( / . ? )
```

Otherwise

```
match "make_tiles(/:tile_type(/:finish))" => "tiles#new", :as => :make_tiles
```

should work fine.